# Web Garden behaves unstable: Users get kicked off randomly

Tags: asp.net-mvc, application-pool, iis-8.5, stateserver, web-garden

I have an ASP.NET MVC web application that was working great under four worker processes (web garden) configuration and using ASP.NET State service to manage incoming sessions.

Session state is configured in Web.config configuration file as below:

```
<system.web>
    <sessionState mode="StateServer" stateConnectionString="tcpip=127.0.0.1:42424" timeout="360" />
</system.web>
```

No machineKey is configured in web.config configuration file and ASP.NET State service runs using the default Network service account.

Additional web server (this is a VMWare virtual machine) details are:

- IIS 8.5.9600.16384
- Windows Server 2012 R2 Standard 64-Bit
- 48GB RAM

Regarding to application pool configuration, some to highlight are:

- 32-Bit application enabled
- Integrated mode and onDemand startup
- Load user profile enabled
- Idle Time-out Action set to suspend
- Rapid fail protection enabled
- Recycling disabled and all limits disabled (set to 0)

Furthermore, Application Pool has always been configured using a custom domain administrator account but currently it has been changed to use a custom non-administrator account due to security reasons.

After changing application pool account, Web Garden has started to behave unstable: users get kicked off randomly. They are getting 403 Unauthorized and 404 Not Found http errors and even I remember to see 503 Service Unavailable.

What can be the cause?

**UPDATE 2020-11-11**:

[image]
[image]

Comment: Nothing can be discussed further unless you get more details from FRT, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/troubleshoot/using-failed-request-tracing/troubleshooting-failed-requests-using-tracing-in-iis

Comment: make sure you set serializable attribute. Objects stored in the session state must be serializable if the mode is set to StateServer. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/ms178586(v=vs.140)?redirectedfrom=MSDN#state-server-mode

Comment: @JalpaPanchal Yes, all objects stored in the session are always marked as serializable using Serializable attribute.

Comment: which kind of user you are using? is it a domain user? try to run failed request tracing in iis. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/troubleshoot/using-failed-request-tracing/troubleshooting-failed-requests-using-tracing-in-iis

Comment: @JalpaPanchal Yes, it is a domain user. The user used before this was a domain administrator user and no problem. But since I use a domain user, these kind of problem don't stop appearing.

Comment: @Ralph please provide the failed request tracing log.

Comment: @JalpaPanchal Ok, i will try to provide the failed request tracing log. Also I will try Debug Diagnostic tool. Meanwhile I provide here some snapshoots about the errors 403 and 404 thrown. See my last update today 2020/11/11.